# Python Argparse use the same argument multiple times

Tags: python, function, dictionary, arguments, argparse

Hi guys I am sitting on a problem so basically, I am working with Argparse and want to use the same argument multiple times

`--filter` takes an argument from the dict list filters and 
`--parameters` pass the parameters for the chosen method from `--filter`

i.e:

```
python filename.py --filter filtermax \
                   --parameter hello 2 \
                   --filter filterPlus \
                   --parameter 6 "hello 9 \
                   --filter printer \
                   --parameter Bye
```

```
filters = {
    "filtermax": filtermax, #(2 parameters String,Int)
    "filtermin": filtermin, #(2 parameters String,Int)
    "filterPlus": filterPlus, #(3 parameters Int,String,Int)
    "printer": printer, #(1 parameter String)
    "printer2": printer2 #(1 Parameter String)
}

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--filter',choices=list(filters.keys()))
parser.add_argument('--parameter',nargs='+')

args = parser.parse_args()
filt = args.filter
para = args.parameter
data = filters[filt](*para)
```

Comment: what is the error/problem you are facing , its unclear from the question you have posted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly what you are looking for is `add_arguments()`'s `action='append'`.

As per [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#action):

> 'append' - This stores a list, and appends each argument value to the list. This is useful to allow an option to be specified multiple times.

In your case, this will create a list of arguments for `filter` and a list of lists for `parameter` (it would make sense to rename this argument to `parameters`).

You would have to adapt your code a bit and add a check to see if the number of arguments passed in match.

```python
import argparse

filters = {
    "filtermax": None,
    "filtermin": None,
    "filterPlus": None,
    "printer": None,
    "printer2": None,
}
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--filter', choices=filters.keys(), action='append')
parser.add_argument('--parameter', nargs='+', action='append')

args = parser.parse_args()
filt = args.filter
# With `nargs='+'` and `action='append'`
# `args.parameter` becomes a list of lists of strs!
para = args.parameter

if len(filt) != len(para):
    raise SystemExit("Number of arguments for filter and parameter don't match!")

# Assuming your intention is to populate the existing `filters` dict:
for fil, par in zip(filt, para):
    filters[fil] = par

print(filters)

# With the arguments you've specified, the output will look like:
# {
#   'filtermax': ['hello', '2'],
#   'filtermin': None,
#   'filterPlus': ['6', 'hello', '9'],
#   'printer': ['Bye'],
#   'printer2': None
#}
```

### NOTES:

- It looks like in your command line invocation, there is an unmatched single double-quote, i.e. `"hello`. For this to work (in bash) you need to remove it or match it, i.e. either `hello` or `"hello"`.
- In a production-type environment, I would add several other checks, for example check if `--parameter` and `--filter` have both been specified at all, or use the [`required` argument](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#required) in `add_argument()`, and exit gracefully if something is missing.
- Even though `add_argument()` has a [`type` parameter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#type), your case is probably too specific to make use of it. With the solution above the `filters` `dict` will contain the arguments passed in to `--parameter` as `list`s of `str`s. If you want to enforce specific types on the passed in parameters, e.g.

> (3 parameters Int,String,Int)

you'll need to have additional checks after getting the arguments from `parse_args()`.